# Access SQL - Query to filter specific records based on whether they ordered in a specific year or not

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called Orders that contains the following fields:
CustomerID, OrderDate

For example

```
1, 01/01/2011
2, 02/02/2011
1, 01/07/2012
```

Am trying to figure out a way to query this table to understand whether a customer ordered in 2011 and has not ordered anything in 2012 and deliver back the distinct customer ID ...

Answer (score 1):

Compare these two approaches to determining which OrderDates are from the year 2012:

1. `Year(OrderDate) = 2012`
2. `OrderDate >= #2012-01-01# AND OrderDate < #2013-01-01#`

The first approach is simple to write and easy to understand.  However it requires the db engine visit every row in your `Orders` table and use that `Year()` function to see whether the row meets your criterion.  That can take a lot of time when the table is large and also if it includes many rows with OrderDates outside your target range.  Most importantly, since that function forces the db engine to examine every row, your query can not make use of indexes to speed up data retrieval.

The second approach, although more verbose, allows the db engine to examine only those rows which satisfy your criterion.  With an index on `OrderDate`, it can easily be an order of magnitude faster than the first approach.

If your table is small enough and/or you're unconcerned about performance, that will not be an issue for you.  However, I'll still suggest you try this version ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT o2011.CustomerID
FROM
    Orders AS o2011
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
        FROM Orders
        WHERE 
                OrderDate >= #2012-01-01#
            AND OrderDate < #2013-01-01#
    ) AS sub2012
    ON o2011.CustomerID = sub2012.CustomerID
WHERE
        o2011.OrderDate >= #2011-01-01#
    AND o2011.OrderDate < #2012-01-01#
    AND sub2012.CustomerID Is Null;
```

Comment: Outstanding ... HansUp the second answer and solution it spot on (need to add a o2011. before the first CustomerID and a couple of .'s in the sub2012 statements) ... this ran is milliseconds v first query that took minutes ... thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 select distinct CustomerID
 from Orders
 where year(OrderDate) = 2011
 and CustomerID not in (
    select distinct CustomerID
    from Orders
    where year(OrderDate) = 2012
    )
```

Comment: Many thanks - worked but took a around 4 mins to run on a 25,000 row access table !!! ... would it be simpler to to do two queries - first to create a table with all the distinct customers that ordered in 2011 and then use those ids to look through 2012 to see if they occur ???

Comment: You can try the solution HansUp suggested to see if there is a performance improvement.  I don't know if using a `LEFT JOIN` (with a `is null` condition) will perform better, but the result will be the same.  And if you do have an index on `OrderDate`, using a date range will certainly be better than the `YEAR` function.  But try them all yourself to see.